# Seeking simple coding example for Axis webcam using Vapix

Tags: jquery, vapix

I should probably ask at the [official Axis developer forum](http://custforum.axis.com/viewforum.php?f=9), but it seems that several have tried that with no success.

Searching through Stack Overflow, I find a few references to Axis cameras and the Vapix API which is a fairly simple-looking HTTP interface - for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751040/anyone-has-an-example-of-a-well-defined-rest-web-service) - so hopefully someone reading this site will be able to help.

The interface looks quite straightforward, but when I execute a GET using JQuery I always end up getting 401 not authorized.

I can't find anything in the available documentation to cover authorization - do I login once, or must I supply user name & password params on each request? (I tried that & it still 401ed)

It seems that the simplest might be if someone can post a few lines of code doing something simple with an Axis (211W) webcam using the Vapix API and I can extrapolate form there.

Anyone? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the API VAPIX doc as it is quite exhaustive.

For example in bash, you can curl the API to get parameter values  :

```
COMMAND="http://$IP:$PORT/axis-cgi/admin/param.cgi?action=list&group=$PARAMETER_TO_GET"
VALUE=$(curl --silent --user "$USER:$PASS" "$COMMAND" | cut -d"=" -f2)
```

You can also transpose this to JQuery or whatever you need.

You only may have to adapt a bit the request, for example using this url format:

```
http://user:password@cam_ip:cam_port/your_command
```

Looking at the code of the camera http server, you'll retrieve this principle in javascript as well.

Note: Path depends on your model and firmware. (/admin is deprecated)

Comment: Including the password in a plaintext URL has been a very bad idea for quite a while. Any proper HTTP stack should be able to accept a username/password and handle real HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the user settings to allow anonymous viewer login and ptz control. On my camera (axis q6034-E) this is in the setup menu under"system options"